# What size of data is allowed by code-mirror?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, codemirror

I need to upload a file and show the corresponding records in codemirror, Is there any limit set by codemirror to the size of data? , so that I can limit the file size needs to upload.

I need to upload a file and show the corresponding records in codemirror.

Comment: https://discuss.codemirror.net/